# How can I get Safari (on Mac) to play MPEG files on my website?

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension

We have lots of media files and I want to play these files on Safari (on Mac) with QuickTime plug-in or VLC Web plug-in or anyting else...

These files' properties:

- Extension: mpg
- Video codec: MPEG Video (PAL) (Version 1)
- Audio codec: MPEG Audio (Version 1) (Layer 2)
- Multiplexed (muxed)

I tried QuickTime plug-in but it does not support the auido codec so the media file was shown with no sound. After a little research I found "QuickTime MPEG-2 Playback Component" which supports MPEG Audio Layer 2. But it is not free... (I have not tried it, maybe it won't work...)

After that I wanted to try "VLC Web plugin for Intel Mac" but it did not work on my Safari. I heard that this project has not developed for 3 years...

Is there any way to get Safari to play MPEG files?

Note: No, I can not change media files' codec...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this `http://perian.org/`

scroll down a little bit on the page and locate the `Perian extends QuickTime support for many popular types of media`.

It should add support for mpeg files to your quicktime player.

Comment: Thanks, but quicktime still does not play audio. i think it's because of these files are muxed.